# How do I install Sinon?

Tags: installation, sinon

Bashing my head against the wall:

Add

```
 "sinon" : "latest"
```

to my bower.json. Install it.

Add sinon to my karma server:

```
files: [
    'vendor/assets/bower_components/sinon/lib/sinon.js',
]
```

Paste the demo expectation into my spec:

```
it("calls the original function", function () {
    var callback = sinon.spy();
    var proxy = once(callback);

    proxy();

    assert(callback.called);
});
```

and:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'sinon.spy()')
```

Why is this? How do I install sinon? Why haven't they bothered with an installation section on their github page?

Answer (score 1):

I came to the same issue, and did the following :

in a command prompt, navigate to the root of your project and type :

```
npm install karma-sinon --save-dev
```

then in your karma.conf.js file add the following:

```
frameworks: ['jasmine', 'sinon']
```

It worked for me